# Как вставить html-тэг в JavaScript

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

скрипт использует ajax и jquery. вот часть скрипта:

```
$("#login").next().hide().text("Логин занят").css("color","red").fadeIn(400);
```

и перед "Логин занят" надо поставить `<br>`, но если его туда просто написать, то никакого эфекта не будет.

Comment: jquery.php файл надо создать и там написать йаваскрипт там бр работает

Answer (score 5):

Метод [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) - возвращает или изменяет html-содержимое выбранных элементов страницы.

```
$("#login").next().hide().html("<br>Логин занят").css("color","red").fadeIn(400);
```

Comment: всё равно не работает

Comment: @Кирилл Романтик, тогда показывайте html-код, относящийся к данной проблеме. Как минимум: элемент с id *login* и следующий за ним элемент.